# Connection between Backend and Frontend Issue

Tags: javascript, python

I have an app that converts pdf files to csv files.  I receive the following error when I press submit with my files `An error occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` .  On my console, it reads `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)` .  It seems that the front end and back end are running on different servers even though I told JSON to go to the same server (port 5000) but the html/js is going to the original JSON script of PORT 5502.  Here is my python file

```
from flask_cors import CORS
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
CORS(app, resources={r"/convert": {"origins": "*"}})


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
def convert():
    print(request.form)
    start_page = int(request.form['start_page'])
    end_page = int(request.form['end_page'])
    filename = request.form['filename']
    output_directory = request.form['output_directory']

    uploaded_file = request.files['pdf_file']  # Get the uploaded PDF file
    pdf_file_path = os.path.join('uploads', uploaded_file.filename)
    uploaded_file.save(pdf_file_path)

    pages_range = f'{start_page}-{end_page}'
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_file_path, pages=pages_range, flavor='stream')

    dataframes = [table.df for table in tables]
    print("Dataframes successfully created.")
    combined_dataframe_vertical = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

    rows_to_remove = []
    merged_rows = []

    for index, row in combined_dataframe_vertical.iterrows():
        if all(pd.isnull(val) or val == '' for val in row[1:]):
            merged_rows[-1] = merged_rows[-1] + row
            rows_to_remove.append(index)
        else:
            merged_rows.append(row)

    combined_dataframe_vertical.drop(rows_to_remove, inplace=True)
    combined_dataframe_vertical = pd.DataFrame(merged_rows, columns=combined_dataframe_vertical.columns)
    combined_dataframe_vertical.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    csv_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f'{filename}.csv')
    combined_dataframe_vertical.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False, header=False)

    response_data = {'message': f"Tables extracted and CSV exported to: {csv_file_path}"}

    return jsonify(response_data)  # Return JSON response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="/static/pdftocsv.js"></script>
    <title>PDF to CSV Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PDF to CSV Converter</h1>

    <div id="drag-area" style="border: 2px dashed #ccc; padding: 20px; text-align: center;">
        <p>Drag a PDF file here to convert</p>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" name="pdf_file" style="display: none;">
    </div>

    <button id="customize-button" style="display: none;">Convert to CSV</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js file

```
const dragArea = document.getElementById('drag-area');
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
const customizeButton = document.getElementById('customize-button');
let pdfFilename; // Declare the variable outside of the event handlers

dragArea.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dragArea.style.border = '2px dashed #000';
});

dragArea.addEventListener('dragleave', () => {
    dragArea.style.border = '2px dashed #ccc';
});

dragArea.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    fileInput.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    pdfFilename = file.name; // Set the PDF filename
    customizeButton.style.display = 'block';
    customizeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Prompt for start page
        const startPage = prompt('Enter Start Page:', '1');
    
        // Prompt for end page
        const endPage = prompt('Enter End Page:', '1');
    
        // Automatically set the output directory to the downloads folder
        const output_directory = 'downloads';
        const defaultCsvFilename = pdfFilename.replace('.pdf', '.csv');
        const customFilename = prompt('Enter File Name:', defaultCsvFilename);
    
        // Send the data to the server for processing
        fetch(window.location.origin + '/convert', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                start_page: startPage,
                end_page: endPage,
                output_directory: output_directory,
                filename: customFilename,  // Only send the custom filename
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            alert(data.message);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
        });
    });
    });

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
        const file = fileInput.files[0];
        pdfFilename = file.name; // Set the PDF filename
        customizeButton.style.display = 'block';
    });
```

Comment: have you tried hardcoding the url in the js script to `127.0.0.1:5000/convert` ?

Comment: comment this line `app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)` try again. you have two instances of `app.run` which is in conflict.